# Cheaper way of calculating this (very) multidimensional derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For an algorithm for a single shooting method a derivative needs to be calculated: 
$$ \frac{\Delta U_N}{\Delta U_0}$$
This is, we have an ODE of the form 
$$y'=f(y)$$
where we have a start value $U_0$ and the end value at time $t_N$, $y(t_N)=U_N$. 
The goal is to see how much $U_N$ "moves" when $U_0$ is moved a certain amount in order to find a $U_0$ with the property $U_0=U_N$ (which for an ODE of this type does not necessarily exist, but for my problem class we can assume it does.)

$y$ is calculated by a numerical method, say we use a simple Euler method. So to calculate the derivative we have to start for two start values, $U_0$ and $U_0+\Delta U_0$ with two numerical solutions $y(t_N,U_0),y(t_N,U_0+\Delta U_0)$, so we get:
$$\frac{\Delta U_N}{\Delta U_0}=\frac{y(t_N,U_0+\Delta U_0)-y(t_N,U_0)}{\Delta U_0}$$

In a scalar setting this costs two times the calculation of a numerical integration. 
**But:** In a vector valued set (as it may arise for a discretized PDE) we would need as many calculations as the vector $U$ has entries! 
My question: is there a way how this derivative can be calculated more cheaply than performing a lot of single derivatives with only one component of $U$ changed by $\Delta U$ each time, which always costs a numerical integration? Any ideas? Thank you.

**Edit:** The actual equation is of the form:
$$Ay'+By=f(t)$$
where $A,B$ are matrices and $f$ a vector valued function of the time.
As far as I get Lutz's idea we could do this:
$$\frac{ \partial^2 y(t,x_0)}{\partial x_0 \partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}f(y)=\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_0}$$
where the value $x_0$ is the initial value (actually $y_0$ but I wanted different variables to avoid confusion). The derivative of $y$ with respect to the initial value seems to be $\dot{A}$, right? 
From here I don't know how this can be used.

**Follow up question** (should this be a new question? If so, I'll repost):

As I got from Lutz's answer, I need to calculate the **fundamental matrix** $\dot{A}=f_y A,A(0)=I$. But: now, as I am actually starting to use this for my algorithm, it seems that it is as expensive as my initial approach. I basically have to run my solver $n$ times ($n$ being the number of entries in my $y_0$-Vector). It is basically this:
$$
x_1'=f_y x_1 \qquad x_1(0)=e_1\\
x_2'=f_y x_2 \qquad x_2(0)=e_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n'=f_y x_n \qquad x_n(0)=e_n
$$
and then assembling the vectors into a matrix $[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$
I don't see the advantage over my naive approach (it first looked charming because it was only one equation, but as I look closer it gets complicated again...). 
Or is there a substantially simpler way to calculate $\dot{A}=f_y A, A(0)=I$? 
Furthermore, how sparse could this matrix be? Sorry for digging this one out again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any close-by solutions to a given solution can be parametrized as $\tilde y=y+εv$. The ODE for the perturbation can be obtained by linearization, i.e., disregarding all higher order terms in the perturbation parameter $ε$.

Use the differentiation rules to find 
$$
\dot{\tilde y}=\dot y+ε\dot v=f(y+εv)=f(y)+εf'(y)v+O(ε^2)4
$$ 
to then find 
$$\dot v=f'(y)v+O(ε),$$ 
which in zeroth order is a linear system. Compute the general solution by computing the fundamental matrix of this linear system, i.e. solve $\dot A(t)=f(y(t))A(t)$, $A(t_0)=I$.

So if you can compute the derivative of $f$, for instance using automatic/algorithmic differentiation, you can augment the ODE system to
$$
\dot y = f(y)\\
\dot A = f'(y)A
$$
$y(t_0)=y_0$, $A(t_0)=I$, so that the solution $y+εv$ for the perturbed initial value $y_0+εv_0$ is in first order $y(t)+εA(t)v_0$.

Comment: I am trying to follow you, but could you please elaborate on that a bit more? Thanks

Comment: Ok, edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks,, I think this pretty much solves my problem.